# Geopy with Pandas cannot take contraints for a region

Tags: google-maps-api, pandas, geopy

The components feature works when we geocode using a single line of code

```
geolocator.geocode(query='AB Vilasam HSS Muhamma', 
    exactly_one=True, 
    bounds=None, region="IN", 
    components=[('administrative_area_level_1','Kerala')]).raw
```

the output is

```
    {'address_components': [{'long_name': 'Muhamma',
   'short_name': 'Muhamma',
   'types': ['locality', 'political']},
  {'long_name': 'Alappuzha',
   'short_name': 'Alappuzha',
   'types': ['administrative_area_level_3', 'political']},
  {'long_name': 'Kerala',
   'short_name': 'KL',
   'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},
  {'long_name': 'India',
   'short_name': 'IN',
   'types': ['country', 'political']}],
 'formatted_address': 'Muhamma, Kerala, India',
 'geometry': {'bounds': {'northeast': {'lat': 9.6272377, 'lng': 76.3879823},
   'southwest': {'lat': 9.592308, 'lng': 76.3397454}},
  'location': {'lat': 9.600587599999999, 'lng': 76.3579401},
  'location_type': 'APPROXIMATE',
  'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 9.6272377, 'lng': 76.3879823},
   'southwest': {'lat': 9.592308, 'lng': 76.3397454}}},
 'partial_match': True,
 'place_id': 'ChIJxauinDWHCDsR0vVLvx4XNwg',
 'types': ['locality', 'political']}
```

However when i use pandas to pass multiple addresses this results in an error

```
df["loc"] = df["doc_loc"].apply(geolocator.geocode(components=[( 'Kerala')]))
```

the output is

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [85], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df["loc"] = df["doc_loc"].apply(geolocator.geocode(components=[( 'Kerala')]))

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:4771, in Series.apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwargs)
   4661 def apply(
   4662     self,
   4663     func: AggFuncType,
   (...)
   4666     **kwargs,
   4667 ) -> DataFrame | Series:
   4668     """
   4669     Invoke function on values of Series.
   4670 
   (...)
   4769     dtype: float64
   4770     """
-> 4771     return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:1123, in SeriesApply.apply(self)
   1120     return self.apply_str()
   1122 # self.f is Callable
-> 1123 return self.apply_standard()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:1174, in SeriesApply.apply_standard(self)
   1172     else:
   1173         values = obj.astype(object)._values
-> 1174         mapped = lib.map_infer(
   1175             values,
   1176             f,
   1177             convert=self.convert_dtype,
   1178         )
   1180 if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], ABCSeries):
   1181     # GH#43986 Need to do list(mapped) in order to get treated as nested
   1182     #  See also GH#25959 regarding EA support
   1183     return obj._constructor_expanddim(list(mapped), index=obj.index)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\lib.pyx:2924, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

df["point"]= df["loc"].apply(lambda loc: tuple(loc.point) if loc else None)
```

Comment: You must use UTF-8 character 'GRAVE ACCENT' (U+0060) aka "Backtick" to delimit code blocks.